# Has anyone tried to use Apache POI on JavaFX modular projects?

Tags: javafx

I've been trying to create a modular JavaFX project with Excel-reporting capabilities. It turned out Apache POI doesn't yet support modular Java apps. Has anyone here tried any work-around on this matter?

Answer (score 0):

I migrated a project initially developed in jdk8, which uses JavaFx to jdk13 using openJfx.

I had to modify the project.properties file quite extensively.

this was done as per openjfx website specifications

```
javac.modulepath=\
D:\\Libraries\\Java9\\openjfx-13.0.2_windows-x64_bin-sdk\\javafx-sdk-13.0.2\\lib

run.jvmargs=--module-path "D:\\Libraries\\Java9\\openjfx-13.0.2_windows-x64_bin-sdk\\javafx-sdk-13.0.2\\lib" \
--add-modules=javafx.base,javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.media,javafx.swing,javafx.web \
```

added these in `run.jvmargs` using trial and error in the sense that the build breaks when it tries to instantiate things...

```
--add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application=ALL-UNNAMED \
--add-exports=javafx.web/com.sun.webkit.network=ALL-UNNAMED \
--add-exports=javafx.web/com.sun.webkit.dom=ALL-UNNAMED \
--add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.scenario.animation.shared=ALL-UNNAMED \
--add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum=ALL-UNNAMED
```

and these are some of the libs it's using

```
javac.classpath=\
${libs.JAVAFX13.classpath}:\
${libs.jsch.classpath}:\
${libs.poi.classpath}:\
```

JAVAFX, poi and jsch are plain libraries. NO extra work was needed here.

apart from the trial and error exports, i essentially followed stuff from this link:

https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-NetBeans